# CMS exposing data as a RESTful API

Tags: content-management-system

Can you recommend a CMS that exposes the entire stored content through some kind of API (HTTP, XML-RPC, web service)?

I want to use it only for creating/editing content, and the content will be then retrieved from another site.

For instance, Wordpress has the type of API I am looking for, but unfortunately it lacks some of the functionality I need (hierarchically organized articles and media, article and image ordering, image galleries...).

Comment: I'm investigating the same area. Looking for a CMS with good API to deliver information to IOS/Android apps... Did you find anything?

Comment: I learned that WordPress has highly customizable backend (I found plugins for almost every functionality I needed) so I can adjust it to my needs.

Comment: I can deliver information to the remote site using XML-RPC API (http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) from the remote side or through small php scripts (written on the server side) that use native WordPress functions (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference). See the example on http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at http://osmek.com/ or http://expressionengine.com/ with the Export it plugin. It allows for channels to be pulled using a REST API.

I have been on a crusade to separate the CMS from the front-end of all of my projects and I have used ExpressionEngine in the past and really dig it. Another plugin that you may like with EE is Playa,it allows for relational data models.

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Check out [prismic.io](http://prismic.io), [contentful.com](http://www.contentful.com) and [osmek.com](http://osmek.com)